# Show/Hide something based on radio click

Tags: meteor

This is template:

```
<template name="TestRadio">
 <form class="form-horizontal">
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="radio" class="control-label">Show/Hide</label>
     <label class="radio-inline">
       <input type="radio" name="showhide" id="show" value="show" checked> Show
     </label>
     <label class="radio-inline">
       <input type="radio" name="showhide" id="hide" value="hide"> Hide
     </label>
   </div>
   {{#if show}}
   <div class="form-group">
     <label for="something" class="control-label">Something</label>
     <input type="text" class="form-control" id="something">
   </div>
   {{/if}}
 </form>
</template>
```

This is helpers:

```
Template.TestRadio.helpers({
  show: function() {
    var type = $('[name=showhide]:checked').val();
    return type === 'show';
  },
});
```

So if the radio value changes, helper `show` should change too. then `input something` should show/hide too.

But it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are telling your template to show `Something` **if** your radio is checked, not **when** it is checked. You will need an event for that.

```
Template.TestRadio.onRendered(function () {
  Session.set('show', false);
});

Template.TestRadio.events({
  'change #hide": function (e) {
    Session.set('show', false);
  },
  'change #show': funciton (e) {
    Session.set('show', true);
  }
});

Template.TestRadio.helpers({
  show: function() {
    return Session.get('show');
  },
});
```